# How to store mp3 files as long blob and play them in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, blob, mp3

I am working on a project which needs to store few mp3 files in database and be able to play them. Using phpmyadmin, I have tried to store mp3 files as long blob objects but the file which I have uploaded is not being displayed. Please help me with it. Also, it would be helpful if anyone can say how to play the songs which are stored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

storing mp3 as blob will cause burden in storing and retrieving as data is converted to binary and stored and is decoded back when retriving from blob to media type object. Instead store it in system location and store the path of it in table will be better approach.

html5 has video attribute and can be used to play video.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Hope your problem is solved

Comment: Could you please answer these?Is storing the path of music file in my system sufficient? How to retrieve the music file if path is stored?